# TextArea Focus using "Tab" in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am able to setfocus to a single cell in JTable using mouseclick, but while using the tab to move between cells, the next selected tab cell just seems to be highlighted, not focused.

Is there a way out to set the focus of a cell using "Tab" key?

Comment: You can still edit it if you begin to write some text into it.

Comment: Yes, but wanted the mouse cursor to be activated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the changeSelection() method of JTable:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...)
{
    //  Place cell in edit mode when it 'gains focus'

    public void changeSelection(
        int row, int column, boolean toggle, boolean extend)
    {
        super.changeSelection(row, column, toggle, extend);

        if (editCellAt(row, column))
        {
            Component editor = getEditorComponent();
            editor.requestFocusInWindow();
//          ((JTextComponent)editor).selectAll();
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, a problem appeared with method #2, where tabbing after a mouse selection took the focus to the first column rather than the next column. I fixed it by calling the `super.changeSelection` after the `if` statement.

```
public void changeSelection(final int row, final int column, boolean toggle, boolean extend)  
{
    if (editCellAt(row, column)) 
    {
        getEditorComponent().requestFocusInWindow();
    }
    super.changeSelection(row, column, toggle, extend);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On selection you need to **edit** the cell and **request focus**. )Also note that you need to add the selection listener for both column and row events.)

---

### Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final JTable t = new JTable(4, 4);
    t.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

    ListSelectionListener l = new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (t.editCellAt(t.getSelectedRow(), t.getSelectedColumn()))
                t.getEditorComponent().requestFocus();
        }
    };
    t.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(l);
    t.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(l);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.add(t);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```